# Terminating app - 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser, unrecognized-selector

I have the following code in my iOS app I had someone create. however, this section of the app breaks and crashes it.

```
   if([[dictHomeSettings allKeys] containsObject:@"notify_url"]) {
        NSString *notifyUrl = [dictHomeSettings objectForKey:@"notify_url"];
        if(notifyUrl.length>0) {
            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
//                    //  You may want to cache this explicitly instead of reloading every time.
//                    NSData *notifyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:notifyUrl]];
//                    NSError* error;
//                    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:notifyData
//                                                                         options:kNilOptions
//                                                                           error:&error];

                XMLDictionaryParser *xmlParser = [XMLDictionaryParser new];
                NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:notifyUrl]];
                NSDictionary *aDict = [xmlParser dictionaryWithParser:parser];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //NSLog(@"myNsArray : %@",aDict);
                    if([[aDict allKeys] containsObject:@"Notification"]) {
                        NSArray *array = [aDict objectForKey:@"Notification"];
                        if(array.count>0) {
                            [Common deletePreviousLocalNotifications];
                            for(NSDictionary *dictNotification in array) {
                                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
                                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

                                if([Common compareDate:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"StartTime"] isGreaterThanOrEqualDate:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]) {
                                    NSLog(@"adding notification : %@",dictNotification);
                                    [Common addLocalNotificationAtDateTime:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"StartTime"]] AlertBody:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"Message"] UserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"URL"], @"URL", nil]];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: You need to point out the exact line causing the error. And you need to update the question with the output of relevant data so we can see what you actually have.

Comment: Your code is most probably crashing on this line  [Common addLocalNotificationAtDateTime:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"StartTime"]] AlertBody:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"Message"] UserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"URL"], @"URL", nil]]; or NSString *notifyUrl = [dictHomeSettings objectForKey:@"notify_url"]; Comment it out and tell me if the app still crashes than i will tell you the solution

Comment: This crash happens when you are assuming a value to be a string but it isn't

Comment: Yes this is the exact line the error happens;  if([Common compareDate:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"StartTime"] isGreaterThanOrEqualDate:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]) { When i comment it out, then error moves to  [Common addLocalNotificationAtDateTime:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"StartTime"]] AlertBody:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"Message"] UserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dictNotification objectForKey:@"URL"], @"URL", nil]];

Comment: how would i edit it? I've tried changing to NSString but doesn't work thanks

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Incorrect. The crash happens when assuming a value is a dictionary when in fact it is actual a string.

Comment: @rmaddy do you have any idea how to fix the issue? Been staring at it for hours. thanks in advance

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Read the exception message. It clearly shows an attempt to call `objectForKey:` (a method from `NSDictionary`) on an `NSString`.

Comment: sorry, im a newbie. Althought I undersand what you're trying to say, I don't know how to fix or implement a fix. If you can kindly tell me what i'm missing and where.

Comment: @kilkinkly Read the very first comment I posted. Until you do it will be too hard to help. But clearly, `array` contains strings, not dictionaries.

Comment: @rmaddy - submitted it earlier. Here's the line(s) [dictNotification objectForKey:@"StartTime"] it does come up as a string.  How can I convert the objectForKey so it'll work?

Comment: Again, please read the very first comment. You need to update your question (not in comments), the line causing the error and you need to show your data. You have yet to show us your data structure.

Comment: what is `common` ? what is `didNotificaation` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call "objectForKey" on a NSString object. Please check whether the objects that you assume to be NSDictionary objects are actually NSDictionary object instances.

Comment: This is the xml it's fetching . It seem to fail on the <id> tag. any ideas? <Notification>
<id>78</id>
<Message>test</Message>
<StartTime>05072016105400</StartTime>
<EndTime>04302016105400</EndTime>
<URL>https://aol.com/page</URL>
</Notification>

Comment: Do u have a semi-colon after the </URL> tag?

Comment: I don't. I think it's a typo when I pasted it. I did double check and the xml is valid. How would I go about changing the NSDictionary to NSString? When I change on page, it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, You are trying to call **objectForKey** on an `NSString` object.     As observed `[dictNotification objectForKey:@"StartTime"]`                         is a `Number` value but you are assuming it is a String (I am not sure on this). So you are getting an `error` on this call

```
[Common compareDate:(Number *) isGreaterThanOrEqualDate:(NSString *)];
```

You can set a `Symbolic breakpoint` with this symbol on -`[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]` to easily `debug` the code.

Comment: See the link for setting symbolic breakpoint  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html